# Eclipse - Android GUI designer incredibly laggy and memory intensive

Tags: android, eclipse, memory, lag

I am having serious issues with the Android GUI designer.

I used to be able to edit views just fine, but I was very far behind on updates.  Once updated, the GUI editor started to lag.

The Image-Buttons in this picture continuously flash as soon as I edit a property on a view.

[image: The controls flash]

And memory usage skyrockets.  Task Manager showed my RAM being completely maxed out at 8 gigs. (javaw.exe ~6.5 gigs of memory usage)

As soon as I switch away from the GUI editor (over to the code editor) it stops lagging, but memory usage stays as-is.

Here is my eclipse.ini configuration

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

It is becoming a burden to work with.

I am running Windows 7 64 bit, with Eclipse and Java 64 bit.