# Android Layout Editor. memory leaks

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-leaks, adt, layout-editor

I've been having problems with the editor layouts in android eclipse. When I start editing a layout, I see that the memory starts to shoot until you get to about 1GB and freeze the eclipse,

I edit normalment for 10 / 15 minutes until it starts to slow down. I tried to fix a number of ways:

- Used Bundle Adt 64 and 32 bits, with their jdk's
- Downloaded an eclipse clean and re-installed the adt plugin sdk 21 and completely.
- Edited the `eclipse.ini` in the best way.

But problems continue.

My pc:

```
Windows 8-64 bit
4GB RAM
Core i3
```

Does anyone have a solution, or it is still a bug in adt?

Comment: I've been having this issue for well over a year now.  No amount of updates have been able to fix it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456789/eclipse-android-gui-designer-incredibly-laggy-and-memory-intensive

Comment: Thank you, it's hard work, but patience.